# ssh -N -f -L*:$PORT:$TARGET:$TARGET_PORT -l $SSH_USER $THROUGH

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I understand this is forwarding requests through a remote machine.

I googled the usage of options of ssh: -N, -f, -L

But what does '*' do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [SSH man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201):

-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
         Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be
         forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.  This
         works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local side,
         optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a con-
         nection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over
         the secure channel, and a connection is made to host port
         hostport from the remote machine.  Port forwardings can also be
         specified in the configuration file.  IPv6 addresses can be spec-
         ified with an alternative syntax:
         [bind_address/]port/host/hostport or by enclosing the address in
         square brackets.  Only the superuser can forward privileged
         ports.  By default, the local port is bound in accordance with
         the GatewayPorts setting.  However, an explicit bind_address may
         be used to bind the connection to a specific address.  The
         bind_address of "localhost" indicates that the listening port be
         bound for local use only, while an empty address or **'*' indicates
         that the port should be available from all interfaces.**

Take note of:

> **'*' indicates**
>          **that the port should be available from all interfaces**